# How do I groupBy, sort and put row data also in new columns in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
id1   id2    c1   c2
1      a1     5     3
1      a1     6     2
1      a1     9     4
2      b1     5     2
2      b1     23    43
1      a1     34    32
3      3a     234   435
```

Now I want to add eight new columns like this:

```
c1_max   c2_max   c1_secondMax   c2_secondMax   c1_thirdMax c2_thirdMax   c1_min   c2_min
```

I want to groupBy `id1` and `id2`

I already added the `c1_max   c2_max   c1_min   c2_min` columns like this:

```
features = ["c1","c2"]
maxData = all_data.groupby(['id1','id2'])[features].agg('max')
all_data = pd.merge(all_data, maxData.reset_index(), suffixes=["", "_max"], how='left', on=['id1', 'id2'])

minData= all_data.groupby(['id1','id2'])[features].agg('min')
all_data = pd.merge(all_data, minData.reset_index(), suffixes=["", "_max"], how='left', on=['id1', 'id2'])
```

But, how do I add `_secondMax` and _`thirdMax`. Basically, they are the second max and third max of those rows.

Comment: What do you want displayed if there are no second or third maxes?  Such as the group has one record?

Comment: @ScottBoston Then the one record multiple times, in all columns

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you have obtained `maxdata` and `mindata`, you can get the `nth` minimums and maximums doing:

```
df.sort_values(['id1','id2','c1']).groupby(['id1','id2']).c1.nth(1)

      id1  id2
1    a1      6
2    b1     23
Name: c1, dtype: int64
```

So in this case you would be obtaining the second minimum for c1

Where `df.sort_values(['id1','id2','c1'])` will sort the values according `id1`, `id2` and `c1` respectively, which is equivalent to grouping by  `id1` and `id2` and sorting `c1`:

```
   id1 id2   c1   c2
0    1  a1    5    3
1    1  a1    6    2
2    1  a1    9    4
5    1  a1   34   32
3    2  b1    5    2
4    2  b1   23   43
6    3  3a  234  435
```

Comment: should we try to match the expected out put ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
smax = lambda x: x[x.rank(ascending = False) == 2]
smax.__name__ = 'secondMax'

tmax = lambda x: x[x.rank(ascending = False) == 3]
tmax.__name__ = 'thirdMax'

df_out = df.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg(['max','min',smax, tmax])
df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in df_out.columns]
df_out = df.merge(df_out, on=['id1','id2'])
df_out = df_out.where(df_out.astype(bool))
df_out
```

Output:

```
   id1 id2   c1   c2  c1_max  c1_min c1_secondMax c1_thirdMax  c2_max  c2_min c2_secondMax c2_thirdMax
0    1  a1    5    3      34       5            9           6      32       2            4           3
1    1  a1    6    2      34       5            9           6      32       2            4           3
2    1  a1    9    4      34       5            9           6      32       2            4           3
3    1  a1   34   32      34       5            9           6      32       2            4           3
4    2  b1    5    2      23       5            5         NaN      43       2            2         NaN
5    2  b1   23   43      23       5            5         NaN      43       2            2         NaN
6    3  3a  234  435     234     234          NaN         NaN     435     435          NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. If there is only one record, then I want it multiple times as `max,`min`,`secondmax` and `thirdmax`, same numbers

Comment: I am getting this error `ValueError: no results` :/ But I guess, you cannot debug it unless I give you the dataframe right?